# Join String and Number to form an array name

Tags: arrays, swift

Here's what I would like to do.

```
number = [ 0, 1, 2]
array0 = [ "AA", "BB"]
array1 = [ "CC", "DD"]
array2 = [ "EE", "FF"]
```

I want to be able to be able to reference the name of the array by doing something like this.

```
selectedArray = "array" + String(number[2])
```

then with this, I would like to be able to reference the values inside such as

```
print("array2:\(selectedArray[1]))
/// The answer would be --> array2:FF
```

Right now, I've not been able to achieve this, and I tried this but it doesn't work.

selectedArray = Array("array" + String(number[2]))

I tried googling but not knowing how to describe this, I didn't fare well in the results.

Note : The array is a list of GPS Dist / Lat / Lon (very long) and rather than have 1 very huge array, I'm thinking of splitting them out into eg: 10 diff arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve and the logic but you can create an array of arrays (lat and long). Something like this:

```
let number = [0,1,2] // not sure why you need this array 
let array = [[ "AA", "BB"],
            [ "CC", "DD"],
            [ "EE", "FF"]]
let selectedNumber = number[2]
print("array\(selectedNumber):\(array[selectedNumber][1])")
```

However, I would advice to use this approach:

1. create a Model for you Coordinates

   ```
   struct Coordinates {
        var lat:String    //this should be a Double but 
                         //for the sake of  the example I use String
        var long:String //Same here
    }
   ```
2. then in the controller add data to an array of `Coordinates`

   ```
    let coordinate1 = Coordinates(lat: "AA", long: "BB")
    let coordinate2 = Coordinates(lat: "CC", long: "DD")
    let coordinate3 = Coordinates(lat: "EE", long: "FF")

    let array2:[Coordinates] = [coordinate1,coordinate2,coordinate3]
    let selectedNumber = number[2]
    print("array\(selectedNumber):\(array2[selectedNumber].long)")
   ```

   which still prints

   ```
    array2:FF
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. in the end, I didn't use this as I went ahead and re-did the whole thing and instead of an array, I just used a json file instead and jsondecoder. (basically, I just copied/pasted something which I've already done). Your model suggestion would fit into my use case tho, but in the end, using the json file is simpler (in my case) since no need to update the "array2" each time I add a new coordinate.